# Soap web service too many read time out

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have wrote some codes to communicate with a webservice and pass some data to it. Below is my code snippet. I have set the readtimeout as 55 seconds which I dont know a suitable value or not? My understanding on readtimeout is the time where last message was send from the server. I dont know what is wrong is it my codes or the server but I get too many read time out? I have listed below the error message which I keep getting. What tweaks can I do to overcome this issue on read time out?

```
void sendData(int dID,String message) throws Exception {  
         SOAPConnection soapConnection = null;
         try{
             SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
             soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
             String url = "http://****/**/***/webservice.asmx?WSDL";
             URL endpoint = new URL (null, "http://****/**/***/webservice.asmx?WSDL", new URLStreamHandler () {  
                 protected URLConnection openConnection (URL url) throws IOException {  
                 // The url is the parent of this stream handler, so must create clone  
                 URL clone = new URL (url.toString ());  
                 URLConnection connection = clone.openConnection ();  
                 // If you cast to HttpURLConnection, you can set redirects  
                 // connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects (false); // no redirs  
                 connection.setConnectTimeout (5 *1000);      // 5 sec  
                 connection.setReadTimeout (55 *1000);         // 55 sec                  
                 return connection;  
             }});  
             SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(createSOAPSending(dID,message), endpoint);         }
         catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
             soapExceptions=1;
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);
             throw e;
         }
         catch (SOAPException e){
             soapExceptions=1;
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);
             throw e;
         }
         catch (Exception e){
             soapExceptions=1;
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.toString());
             System.out.println(e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);
             throw e;
         }
         finally{
             try{
                if ( soapConnection != null ){
                  soapConnection.close();
                  soapConnection=null;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("is null ");
                }
              }
              catch(SOAPException ex){
                  System.out.println("SOAPException has been caught for soapConnection close");
                  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
              }
         }


    }

     SOAPMessage createSOAPSending(int dID,String message) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
         SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
         SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
         // SOAP Envelope
         SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
         SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
         SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("sData","", "http://***"));
         element.addChildElement("dID").addTextNode(dID);        
         element.addChildElement("pmessage").addTextNode(message);
         MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
         headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://*****");  
         soapMessage.saveChanges();
         /* Print the request message */
         soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
         return soapMessage;
    }
```

Here are the error logs.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1659)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1657)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1240)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1661)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1659)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 4 more
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1657)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1240)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:265)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
... 4 more
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:643)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1319)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:245)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:643)
... 4 more
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1319)
```

Comment: Test the interface with SoapUI, JMeter or similar and see how long the requests take. If they take more then the 55s limit you set (which sounds as a high limit already), then the service is really slow and you might need to set it even higher.

Comment: Yes I rest in soapui it also gets the read time out there too. So my question is something wrong with my codes causing it to slow or indeed is the service? What is suitable value for readtimeout?

Comment: Is the posted code the producer or the consumer? I do not see anything strange in your code which might cost you the >55s. The usual advice: test in a debugger which line takes the >55s, check your DNS too please. Also look into axis2: way less code to write sice all the soap stuff is handled by axis2.

Comment: I am not sure on when you say producer or consumer. what is does just pass data into the webservice. So can I say its more of the server rather than the codes then ?